# How to put padding on SPAN only when not empty

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML source:

```
<span id="ctl00_SiteMap1" class="breadcrumb hidOverflow">
    <span>
        <a title="Homepage" href="/Default.aspx">Home</a>
    </span>
    <span></span>
    <span>
        <a title="Basic Reporting Samples" href="/find_provider.aspx">Provider</a>
    </span>
    <span></span>
    <span>Profile</span>
</span>
```

The following CSS:

```
.breacrumb {
    font: 10px 'Verdana', 'Graduate', 'Arial', 'Helvetica', 'sans-serif';
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #9b9b9b;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.breadcrumb li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.breadcrumb a {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-image: url('../theImages/breadCrumbArrow.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    padding-right: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #454545;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.breadcrumb span a:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

How can I modify my CSS to do the following:

- Add another condition along with `.breadcrumb span
  a:not(:first-child)` so that each SPAN after will have the `padding:
  15px` (e.g. Provider and Profile) and not the empty span in between.
- Make the last non-empty span (Profile) color to #CCCCCC.

Updated CSS which adds padding to all three texts:

```
.breadcrumb span:first-child a {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.breadcrumb span:not(:empty) {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: You misspelled `.breadcrumb` . . .

Comment: `.breadcrumb span a:not(:first-child)` does not target anything because in your provided code, the anchor is always a first-child of the span container

Comment: Updated my question with the updated CSS but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a complete solution

You need to

Kill padding on the first anchor

```
.breadcrumb span:first-child a {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Add padding for non empty spans

```
.breadcrumb span:not(:empty) {
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Since first span is not empty, you need to kill padding for first span

```
.breadcrumb span:first-child { 
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
.breadcrumb span:not(:empty) {
    padding:15px;
}
.breadcrumb span:last-child:not(:empty) {
    color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: The first one puts padding on first and that's all. The last one still has no padding :/

Comment: Think I have to expand on this: `.breadcrumb span a:not(:first-child) {
 padding-left: 15px;
}`

Comment: All of your a tags are first-childs of the parent spans so that rule will not match any of them

Comment: `.breadcrumb span:last-child:not(:empty)` will not work if last span is empty although I don't think the last span will be empty anyway so there is point to have the `not(:empty)` part

Comment: I think i have to put my CSS second for the first `A` because with the first code from yours it resets the first one.

Comment: empty span AND first `a` cannot have any padding. This is where the confusion is.

Comment: @SiKni8 target the first anchor by using `.breadcrumb span:first-child a`

Comment: Didn't work. I updated my question to what I have so far and it is putting a padding to all three texts.

Comment: @SiKni8 well `.breadcrumb span:not(:empty) ` is targeting the first span so you get padding. Just do `.breadcrumb span:first-child { // set padding to 0 }`

Comment: Yep :(. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Can you add an answer with your solution? It will be easier that way. I don't down vote unless it doesn't relate :)

Comment: @SiKni8 added, I put comments on each line so you understand how it works

Comment: @JonathanCrowe Thank you for the code, it helped set the way. Up voted.